# Beautiful Soup returning only the last URL of a txt file

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse a set of url of a txt file, but Beautiful Soup is returning only the content of the last url. It's a set of urls with movie reviews from the website LetterBoxD. For example, if the file has 10 urls, I'm getting "none" for the first 9. Only the 10th is returning properly. Can someone help me?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open('list_of_urls.txt', 'r') as f:
  x = f.readlines()

for url in x:
  page = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  text = soup.find(class_='review body-text -prose -hero -loose')
  print(text)
```

Comment: perhaps your specified class only exists in the page source of the last url?

Comment: Mind sharing a sample of those 10 urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much! But I found out that the URLs had a \n at the end. So I used rstrip('\n') to delete it.

Btw, Alexandra's tip help a lot for future extraction! Thank you!

This is my new code:

```
for url in x:
  url = url.rstrip('\n')
  page = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  text = soup.find(class_='review body-text -prose -hero -loose')
  print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding element by several classes an array of class names should be used:

```
text = soup.find(class_= ['review', 'body-text', '-prose', '-hero', '-loose'])
```

It also seems, that letterboxd.com may have different combination of classes on review element, e.g. `review body-text -prose -hero prettify`, so I would recommend to search after less classes, e.g.

```
text = soup.find(class_= ['review', 'body-text'])
```